# Using model in login form in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I have a view which has textboxes. I send texbox parameters to my controller method but the admin model's username and password properties are bound from the request and have the same values as the Username and Password arguments. So how can I use my model for login control ? By the way admin model's has admin_id. Thanks for your help

```
 public ActionResult Login(admin model,string Username,string Password)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                if (model.username == Username && model.password == Password)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.username, false);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Kontrol");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong username or password");
                }
            }
             return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have two `Username` and `Password` values from inputs? Try next names for admin model:

```
model.username
model.password
model.admin_id
```